# C program with return carriage \r

Tags: c

**How do I write a C program that allows me to make carriage return for each white space in the Input ?**

Like for example :

Input : "I love programming"

Output :

```
I 
love
programming
```

What I did :

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int main() {
    
    

int ch;
 char str[50];

while ((ch = getchar()) != EOF) {
  putchar(isspace(ch) ? '\r' : ch);
}
  scanf("%s", str);
  printf("%s", str);

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please ask a question. Explain what problem you have that prevents you from progressing the code.

Comment: *the output contains a carriage return (\r) between any line break*. That's not what the example output shows. Looks like "line break" really should be "white space".

Comment: One way: Write a loop that looks at each character of `str`. If it is a space then output a newline otherwise output the character directly.

Comment: Your question is a bit unclear. Please write the EXACT assignment you have.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read a character.  If a *white space*, print a `'\r'`

```
#include <ctype.h>

int ch;
while ((ch = getchar()) != EOF) {
  putchar(isspace(ch) ? '\r' : ch);
}
```

---

Or if you want a *new line*:

```
  putchar(isspace(ch) ? '\n' : ch);
```

Comment: Ok it looks good, but I don't know how to insert it in my code

Comment: @Newbie No need for `char str[50]; ... scanf("%s", str); printf("%s", str);` as this answer's code replaces that I/O.